# CSS - How to display dropdown text in one row?

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm building a dropdown menu and I've got an issue showed on this img:
[image]

I want the "2.1" text to be displayed next to the "Item" text. For some reaason, every new word gets a new line.

Here's the html:

```
<ul id='nav'> 
    <li><a href='/'>Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='/'>Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='/'>Item 2.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/'>Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='/'>Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='/'>Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#nav li ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 20px;   
    text-align: left;
    background: #999;
}
```

Thanks for any help, Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is adding a nowrap property to `#nav li ul li a`:

```
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 20px;   
    text-align: left;
    background: #999;
    white-space: nowrap;  /* Forbids text wrapping */
}
```